# C++ Can't read pointer-offsets chain, getting random invalid numbers

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

the function below worked as intended before, no changes were made, but now I'm getting invalid output when reading pointer value for the first time. So, the fist time I read pointer value with ReadProccessMemory the addr turns from 0x58AC00 into 0x127ca7c800765d50, and it's not the address in decimal, nothing meaningful... I noticed this weird transformation occurs only the first time I'm trying to read the pointer chain, so the next 2 iterations offsets are added to addr as intended. Any help, would be glad!

I pass offsets as std::vector ( 0x374, 0x14, 0x0)
hProc is valid.

```
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}
```

I've tried to replace (BYTE*) cast with (LPCVOID) but it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using `ReadProccessMemory()` at all this is not intended to be an IPC method.

Comment: ***Any help, would be glad!*** I doubt we can help given only this function. Maybe if you show a memory dump of the process you are trying to read someone could help correct the addresses.

Comment: Well I already know the address and can read it's value when I'm passing it to the RPM directly, the problem is that I can't read pointer using rpm

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong address. Maybe the pointer does not point to what you think it does.

Comment: `addr += offsets[i];` note that thus offsets will be added in units of `sizeof(unit_t)` if the offset is in bytes this won't work as you expected. Also an offset of `0x0`  will not add anything

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I just forgot to change my configuration from x64 to x86, so the pointer sizes did not match. That caused this problem. Better to pay more attention to project settings.